# Xcode Particle Emitter Editor not using ~ipad images?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, sprite-kit, skemitternode

We have different images for iPhones and iPads, but the Particle Emitter Editor in Xcode only seems to use the iPhone images -- even on iPad devices.

We also tried changing the texture in code like this:

```
emitterNode.particleTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Test.png")
```

We have an image named "Test@2x~ipad.png". This is the iPad version of the image.

The iPhone version is named "Test@2x.png".

Is automatically using different images for different devices not possible with SKEmitterNodes, or are we doing something wrong?

Comment: @matt yup, that is a possibility. just trying to see if there's a less hacky way of doing it, meaning all from the particle editor (since everything else is controlled by the particle editor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `SKTexture(imageNamed: "Test.png")`, call `SKTexture(image: UIImage(named: "Test"))`. The call to `UIImage(named:)` will obey the bundle resource naming conventions.

Comment: so SKTexture(ImageNamed: "Test.png") isn't supposed to obey bundle resource naming conventions? thanks for sharing!

Comment: I don't know whether it does or not. But I do know that `UIImage(named:)` does!

Comment: fair enough, will try this approach and see if it works! thanks again.

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work ... any other suggestions? the texture size of the new image prints out correctly, but it seems like the particle's texture size is stuck with the size of the particle's original image/texture. in other words, the image itself changes, but the size doesn't.

Comment: Ah yes, the size. As I recall, you don't use 2x images for emitters. Is that the problem?

Comment: actually i think the problem is you must explicitly change the particle size after changing the texture/image. will try that and grant you credit if it works.

Comment: I don't see why I get any credit, but do keep me posted on what happens. :)

Comment: yup updating the emitter's `particleSize` property was the problem. see answer below. can even use `SKTexture(imageNamed: "Test.png")` as well. you get credit for helping out! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer but gave @matt the points since he helped out.

Unfortunately it seems like the Xcode Particle Editor won't automatically recognize the iPad image via the `~ipad` naming convention.

The solution is to specify the texture in code, but you must also update the particle size like this:

```
            let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Test.png")
            emitterNode.particleTexture = texture
            emitterNode.particleSize = texture.size()
```